# How can i access values returned by Hibernate Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, hql

How can i access the elements from the list created as below? I tried creating a class containing a String and an int and cast to it but it doesn't work.

```
 List SOList = iadao.getSession().createQuery("select a.sistemOperare, count(a.sistemOperare) from User a, IstoricAfisari b, Banner c, Advertiser d where b.bannerId = c.id and c.advertiserId = d.id and b.userId = a.id group by a.sistemOperare").list();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces a List of Object arrays -> `List<Object[]>`

Comment: yes, which will have values like ['Windows',30]. How can i get to this values?

Comment: if `List<Object[]>` represents to complete result set, `Object[]` represents a row in the result set. So I guess you are able to figure out what the values of the object array are ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since the createQuery(HQL).list() returns a List matching the indexes of the selected fields:

```
List SOList = ...
for (Object obj : SOList) {
    Object[] fields = (Object[]) obj;
    System.out.println("sistemOperare = " + fields[0] + " (count = " + fields[1] + ")");
}
```

Would print the results from the query, if any. According to hibernate documentation I could find (Since I'm more used to creating criteria for objects I want and then use Java for the rest).